# Как показать Popup после 5 запуска приложения?

Tags: c#, messagebox, popup, windows-phone-8

Всем доброго времени суток. Проблема следующая: хочу сделать кастомное диалоговое всплывающее окно, которое будет предлагать пользователю написать отзыв на почту, либо воспользоваться MarketplaceReview. Нужно чтобы данное окно отображалось после 5 запуска приложения. Как это сделать?

Comment: Вы приложение уже написали? Начните с него...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У Microsoft есть [демо-пример](https://github.com/Microsoft/rate-my-app) на эту тему. Качайте, разбирайтесь. Там есть и логика по ослеживанию количества запусков, и логика по вызову MarketplaceReview, и логика показа сообщений пользователю.

Вкратце работает это так:

1. Заводится настройка -- количество запусков приложения. На выходе это
   количество увеличивается и сохраняется.
2. При запуске считывается количество запусков и если оно достигло
   нужного порога, пользователю выводится сообщение.
3. Опционально при его отказе можно продолжить отслеживать количество
   запусков и предложить еще раз спустя некоторое время. После второго
   отказа уже никогда не показывать.